# close XML : when read excel cant get dataValidation type List from another sheet c#

Tags: c#, closedxml

I have an excel worksheet, with two sheets
sheet1:  contains the source  lists
sheet2: contains the cell with dataValidation lists settings

the problem is closeXML does not recognize the lists.
(when dataValidateion in same sheet with source list it's OK
even when we try to get

```
cell.HasDataValidation
```

I get true if the dataValidation source list in same sheet, but false if dataValidation source list in another sheet